# Error while indexing VARCHAR(32000) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have several millions of files and each file may have several thousands of functions. I have to store the names of these files and functions in a MySQL table to display this in a UI. The file names will be of length up to 100 characters and the function names may range from 300 to 32000 characters. I created a separate table for storing function names as most of them are redundant and it was consuming lot of space. Below are the details of the tables:

```
create table files (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    file_name VARCHAR(100),
    function_id int,
    primary key(id) using btree
    CONSTRAINT `unique_functions` FOREIGN KEY (`function_id`) REFERENCES functions(id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)

create table functions (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    function_name varchar(32000) not null COLLATE 'latin1_general_cs',
    primary key(id) using btree
)
```

I query for the function IDs as below to insert them in files table:

```
select ID from functions where function_name= 'some_name';
```

But the performance of the query is very slow so I tried to create an index on function_name column but it fails with below error:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX function_name_unique ON functions(function_name);

#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

I tried looking for a solution but could not find much help. Most of the articles say it is bad practice to create an index on long texts but I am not sure if i can avoid that? Any ideas are really appreciated.

NOTE:
I also found that we can use prefix length for INDEX but most of my function names are same in the beginning and I am not sure of this will be helpful in this case.

Comment: This is an inherent limitation on indexes in mysql. There is no explicit way to get around it. You can try to hash the function names and search for the hash as opposed to the function name. However, this enables exact searches only.

Comment: Btw, an index on function_name is not going to speed that query up.

Comment: I presume there's a size limit because otherwise you risk having an index as large as the actual data. You normally overcome this with hashes for exact search and full text indexes for natural language search.

Comment: I have to insert several millions as quickly as possible and worried that creating hashes will put additional CPU overhead. But will try and see. Thank You. @Shadow

Comment: @breakingpython adding an index on the name column is not going to speed your query up as the join is on function_id field and there is no where clause, so nothing could use the index.

Comment: Then you need the hashes.

Comment: @shadow  I need function_ids while inserting into files table and that is where I am facing slowness. That is why I wanted to index function_name.

Comment: @Shadow I will explore hashes. Thank You.

Comment: I may have missed something, but an index will also slow down insertions.

Comment: calling 32k of text a "name" that might be provided to search strains the concept of naming

Comment: If it is a uniqueness check, then create a generated column that hashes the file name and add a unique index on top of it. But it WILL slow you insertions down. By how much - you need to measure.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am okay with the insertion slowness.

Comment: @Shadow In the beginning I stored function names along with file names all in one table. But over the time the table size has reached several gigabytes as function names are duplicated. So I moved the function names to a separate table to reduce the storage consumption as most of the function names are redundant. And I will insert only unique function names in the functions table.

Answer (score 0):

- Load all the data into a table without the desired Unique index(es).  If this is `LOAD DATA`, it will be very fast.
- Have an extra column for the hash.
- Generate the hashes.   Do you need to do this in the app?  Or in SQL?
- Now add the indexes.  This is 'fast enough'.

MariaDB has a "hash" index to help with such.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But Our only available option is MySQL. We cannot switch to any other databases. And this is not a one time activity. We repeat every day with new data where there will be incremental updates for function names and file names.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (Relevant to my second Answer.)

Comment: It is MySQL 8.0

Comment: 8.0 has SPs, generated columns, and functional indexes.  So there are a variety of ways to "hide" the creation and use of the kludge.

Answer (score 0):

In the table, include

```
full_fcn_name TEXT NOT NULL,
fcn_end VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
INDEX(fcn_end)
```

You would have to do things like:

```
INSERT ... (... fcn_end, full_fcn_name)
    VALUES
    (..., RIGHT(?, 100), ?)
```

and

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE fcn_end = RIGHT(?, 100)
      AND full_fcn_name = ?
```

(A similar approach would involve `REVERSE()`.)

The above could be "hidden" from the users via Stored Routines, "Generated columns", "functional indexes", app subroutines, etc.  (This depends on the specific version of MySQL/MariaDB you are using.)

Note: A prefix index does *not* provide a usable `UNIQUE` test.  (One the prefix amount is checked for uniqueness.)  See other suggestions for using a Hash.

Comment: Is this assuming the last 100 characters offer uniqueness? Will it also help if they are repetetive?

Comment: No.  Notice that `CREATE` says `INDEX`, not `UNIQUE`. And the `SELECT` double-checked with the full name.

Comment: So we will insert last 100 characters as a separate column and index it. And this will be used to improve the query performance. If there are duplicates, we are ensuring the uniqueness with full_fcn_name. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is the idea.